# PBKDF2 encryption on Laravel authentication

Tags: django, authentication, encryption, laravel, pbkdf2

I need to create an application with Laravel authentication system that matches password from a Django database, Django uses PBKDF2 to hash a password. ([Django encryption info here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/passwords/))

Answer (score -1):

You will need to write it. Blowfish is considered more secure though, just for your understanding.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I have no choice, I need to validate my application with the existing Django users :(

Comment: Then you will need to rewrite Django's hashing algorithm in Laravel.  Which to be fair, is fairly simple because PBKDF2 has plenty of code online you can use.

Comment: Blowfish is a symmetric block cipher, PBKDF2 is - well - a password based key derivation function. "Blowfish is considered more secure though" doesn't make much sense. Apples and pears.

Comment: No, we're talking about password hashing here. So in the world of hashing a password securely and irreversibly we can absolutely compare the two. In fact, we could compare them to md5 and to manually changing the letters around - it's not about how they do it but how well they hide the data you need hidden. And to bed fair they both hide it so well that the best computers in the world would take thousands or millions of years to crack a random password hashed with either one of them.